# What does one find out by looking at ‘hops?’

Tags: iphone, ipad, lan, spyware

Someone is tracking my iPad/iPhone using NetMaster and GeoTrace apps. They use GeoTrace (so they say) to monitor my text messages. Only portions or sentences (which I don’t recognize) that are supposedly from my iPhone show in saved GeoTrace searches.

He also has many screen shots he took of hops he has traced that supposedly show my internet searches (none of which I recognize.) What does one find out by looking at ‘hops?’

Answer (score 0):

"Hops" refer to the route internet traffic takes from one host to another. On the internet packets are often routed through multiple intermediate hosts to get to their final destination. You could say that a packet "hops" from one host to another giving rise to the term. It doesn't have anything to do with internet searches.

"GeoTrace" looks like just a fancy GUI to the standard `traceroute` program which does not and cannot monitor text messages. All it does is show the route between you and another host.

Comment: Thanks! So this doesn't necessarily mean each and every one on the hop list was searched and/or visited on my iPad or iPhone, correct?

Comment: No, that would just mean that the traffic from whichever host they traced the route to went through those hosts. I bet most of the hosts don't even respond to web traffic or anything that would constitute "visiting" in the usual sense.